# Promise chaining, "this" is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-promise

In my provider I have the following code (simplified):

```
  initiateAPI(): Promise<any> {
      return this.method1()
        .then(this.method1)
        .then(this.method2)
        .catch(console.log);
  }
```

Both the *method1* and *method2* methods return a Promise, as follows:

```
  method1() : Promise<any> {
    console.log("this in method 1",this);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.anotherProvider.getData().then((data) => {
        if(!data) {
          reject("Data not found");
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

 method2() : Promise<any> {
    console.log("this in method 2",this);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.thirdProvider.getData().then((data) => {
        if(!data) {
          reject("Data not found");
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

The first method (*method1*) executes correctly and the second method (*method2*) is called, as expected. The problem is that `this` is undefined in the second method.

I have also tried to chain the promises as follows:

```
  initiateAPI(): Promise<any> {
      return this.method1()
        .then(() => this.method1)
        .then(() => this.method2)
        .catch(console.log);
  }
```

But the problem remains the same.

How can I make `this` keep its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods are implemented as old-fashioned `function` functions, so not as arrow functions, which means `this` is determined by the way the methods are called. As you provide a function reference as the `then` callback, `this` will be `undefined` (or the global object in sloppy mode).

There are at least two ways to keep `this` as you want it:

```
initiateAPI(): Promise<any> {
    return this.method1()
        .then(_ => this.method1())
        .then(_ => this.method2())
        .catch(console.log);
}
```

or:

```
initiateAPI(): Promise<any> {
    return this.method1()
        .then(this.method1.bind(this))
        .then(this.method2.bind(this))
        .catch(console.log);
}
```